# How to collect the same cookies of one domain to another domain from the same browser?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I have opened an anonymous website say **example.com** in a browser. Now I am running a PHP script which runs in another domain say **test.com** which is owned by me in another Tab from the same browser.
How can I get all the cookies which were set in **example.com** into my **test.com** PHP script?
The objective is to collect all the same cookies that were set in **example.com** & process those same cookies in my PHP script.

Any advice would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get cookie information from one domain to another. It would be a massive security hole.

If you absolutely need the values, you will need to add a page to domain1 which reads the cookie and redirects to domain2, passing the cookie values as a query string or form parameter.

Comment: Is it possible If I load it in an iframe?

Comment: No, again it would be a security/privacy issue.

Comment: Is there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: No, you would have to have a page in domain1 whose code you would use to read the cookie values to pass to domain2. If domain1 is one that you do not have access to the code base you will not be able to do this at all. What, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to do a Add to cart function to an ecommerce website from my domain that shows cart information in the ecommerce website

Comment: The goal is to verify the prices are accurate

Comment: Do you own domain1?

Comment: No I don't own the ecommerce domain

Comment: Then you need to rethink your logic because there is no way that you can get access to the cookies on that site.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your advice. Will rebuild the logic. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible If I load my domain in an Iframe to the ecommerce website by getting proper access

Comment: No, you cannot get the cookies from an iframe to pass to the parent when they are different domains.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your time & consideration. Now all makes sense